# Sum of two nonstationary exponential distribution.

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, poisson-process, time-series

Suppose I have nonidentical exponentially distributed random variables $X$ with a time-variant rate of $\lambda_X(t)$ and $Y$ with a time-variant rate of $\lambda_Y(t)$. What is the distribution of $Z = X + Y$? Is it a hypoexponential distribution or a gamma distribution?

Still related to the above questions, if I have $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ based on the formula we obtained above, what is the distribution of $Q = Z_1 + Z_2$?

Any references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution when $\lambda_X \neq \lambda_Y$ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution for when equality does hold.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "exponentially distributed random variable with a time-variant rate"? It sounds like you're describing an inhomogenous Poisson process, which is a stochastic process - that is, a collection of random variables indexed on $[0,\infty)$ - as opposed to an individual random variable. (And so, the question of its "distribution" is unclear.)

Comment: @daisies Thanks for the reference. In the Hypoexponential function described in Wikipedia, the parameter $\lambda$ in the PDF $f(x)$ is not as a function as x. It would be helpful to know the distribution when $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are inhomogeneous and as a function of x.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you very much for your response. You are correct, I am referring to the multiple independent and inhomogeneous Poisson process. I apologize for the confusion. Let me be very clear this time. Suppose two Poisson processes operate independently. The interarrival time of these two Poisson processes is X and Y with arrival rates $\lambda_X(t)$ and $\lambda_Y(t)$, respectively. I am having trouble formulating the pooled interarrival time $Z$, where $Z=X+Y$. In addition, I was curious about the distribution of $Q=Z_1+Z_2$.

Comment: Right, so my point is moreso that such a distribution cannot be easily described, since in the case where $\lambda_X, \lambda_Y$ are constant in $t$ there is already no easy description, so certainly there shouldn't be much hope for when they vary in $t$; as Math1000 mentioned, this process $Z$ should probably be indexed by $t \geq 0$ where each $Z_t$ is Erlang.